# NSXMLParserでタグの子要素と属性を取得したい。

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

NSXMLParserでタグの子要素と属性を取得したい。
NSXMLParserDelegateのデリゲートメソッドの引数であるattributeDictで取得できると考えていたのですが、print(attributeDict)っと中身を見てみると

```
[:]
[:]
[:]
```

のようになっていて取得できない。

以下の`<img>`要素の`src`属性を取得したい。

```
<![CDATA[
<div id="div_4iDn9fNCNpE"></div> <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery("#div_4iDn9fNCNpE").append('<a href="/2997"><img src="http://inutube.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/SnapCrab_NoName_2015-12-7_13-47-18_No-00-e1449463969863.png" /></a>');
]]>
```

Comment: [NSXMLParserDelegateのリファレンス](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/)を参照するとよいですが、CDATAセクションの場合は`parser(_:foundCDATA:)`が呼び出されますね。

Comment: parse‌​r(_:foundCDATA:)を使ってCDATAの中身を取得できました。中身の<img src""/>を取得したいのですが、どのように取得できるのでしょうか。

Comment: 「`NSXMLParser`で」という条件だと難しいと思います。これがパースできるのはあくまで純粋なXMLだけですが、この`<img>`要素はJavaScriptソースの一部ですので。推測ですが、このサイトのRSSフィードから画像のサムネイル一覧を作りたいのでしょうか？もしそのような用途であれば、正規表現などの文字列操作で決め打ちして取得することはできると思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/21966